# Is there any SQL injection for this PHP login example?

Tags: web-application, authentication, php, sql-injection, mysql

I want to write a login form, and I got one example from the web.
I want to know, if there is any SQL injection for this code? If there is, what could the exploit's web form entry look like?

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <dt class="title"><label for="username">name:</label></dt>
    <dt><input type="text" name="username" id="username"  size="50"></dt>
    <dt class="title"><label for="password">pass:</label></dt>
    <dt><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="50"></dt>
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

and this is my check:

```
if (($post[username]) AND ($post[password])) 
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE `config_admin_username`="'.$post[username].'" AND `config_admin_password`=MD5("'.$post[password].'") LIMIT 1';
        $sql_user_check = $db->fetch($query);
        if (!$sql_user_check) { 
            $error .= "Wrong Entry.<br />";
        } else {
            $_SESSION[admin] = 1;
            header("Location:index.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

I'm using phpmyadmin 3.2.0.1 on wamp 2.0i

Comment: If you are new to PHP, I would not recommend writing your own logon form. I would try to plug in some framework or at least find an example where the author stresses security in the title.  You should of course now how to look for faults, but there are many complexities and bad things that can happen even beyond SQL injection from a logon form.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've come to the right place. Welcome to [IT security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)!

> is there any sql injection for this code?

**Yes**

> if there is what is that Entry?

```
username: [any username from your website]" /*
password: sux0r")*/ OR ("1"="1
```

It will run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `config` 
WHERE `config_admin_username`="[any username from your website]" /* 
      AND `config_admin_password`=MD5("sux0r")*/ OR ("1"="1") LIMIT 1'
```

If we remove the commented-out parts that SQL engine won't parse, this results in:

```
SELECT * FROM `config` 
WHERE `config_admin_username`="[any username from your website]" OR ("1"="1") LIMIT 1'
```

SQL query will be parsed up till the commented out part (I used the `/*` and `*/` start-comment/end-comment pair in my example and assuming you're using [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html), but that can be different depending on RDBMS used), effectively disabling your password check altogether. Even if in-SQL commenting is not supported, or disabled, the options to exploit your login are really limitless. I won't even go into your choice of MD5 as a password hashing algorithm, as you have a lot of other things to consider first. It clearly isn't the recommended hash algorithm for password hashing though.

You've done good to have come to this website and that you're asking yourself questions regarding your code safety. Congratulations, you're already a better PHP programmer than most that never got so far are! Now, it's up to you what you'll learn from already existing questions and answers here. Some tags to consider are [php](/questions/tagged/php), [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication), [web-application](/questions/tagged/web-application), [hash](/questions/tagged/hash),...

Comment: tnq for reply , but stil script give me Wrong Entery.

Comment: @sorroshsaket - Like I mentioned, the syntax for the commenting out might be different, you didn't provide information to what database you're using. It's trivial to test other options tho, but I can't include all possible ways to exploit it, the answer would stretch several pages long. The point is, you're not sanitizing input parameters at all, and any value directly affecting the SQL syntax of your query can be passed through them. Try with `" OR 1=1 LIMIT 1 /*`. But please provide more information too, so we're not shooting in the dark here.

Comment: i'm using phpmyadmin 3.2.0.1 on wamp 2.0i

Comment: @sorroshsaket - I've updated my answer to reflect that. [MySQL comment syntax is explained here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

Comment: when i print $query output is 
SELECT * FROM `config` WHERE `config_admin_username`="admisdn" OR 1=1 /*" AND `config_admin_password`=MD5("sux0r")*/ OR ("1"="1") LIMIT 1
 But there is no answer . this out put is befor $res = $this->execute($query);
when i set $query with this data it works fine
is there any thing on $query that when i use echo disapear?

Comment: @sorroshsaket - There might be no reply, if you didn't set up your `index.php` as is configured in the code that executes if the query was successful. The point of this _exercise_ was to not get the `Wrong Entry.` reply but to execute the code that's to be run after a successful login authentication (or in our case a SQL-injection hack). But what should happen after the authentication is another point. If you have programming questions, I suggest you search for answers or post new questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Security related questions should stay here, though. ;)

Comment: tnQ 
it's security Question . I Found the problem .
Your Entry Was Currect as my Entry . but When i insert an " from input that is &quot that change query to a wrong entry . 
what i must do for inject? PLZ help . almost finished :D

Comment: @sorroshsaket - There is nothing in your code that you included that would suggest `"` double quote character to be replaced with it's HTML encoded representation of `&quot;`. If you have some other parts of your code that are relevant, then please include that in your question. But depending on your _[magic-quotes](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-magic-quotes.php)_ setup, you should be able to get around it with \ preceding any single or double quote characters. Try with `admisdn\" OR 1=1 /*\"` and `sux0r\")*/ OR (\"1\"=\"1` but you should really learn to debug to see where the problem is. ;)

Comment: i set this code before execute and $query work fine
$query=str_replace('&quot;','"',$query);
but in real i haven't this access , i there any way for use " ?

Comment: @sorroshsaket - I'm getting this distinct feeling this is not [white hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security)) any more. Either that, or there's something _lost in translation_? Besides, if double quotes are escaped in some input parameter sanitization, there's actually a whole lot easier way to get around it by using parts of my examples. But as I said, I'm not sure this is within the ethical hacking limits. Are you trying to harden your own authentication process, or hacking your way into a website that isn't yours? Sec.SE does not support black hats! Please confirm.

Comment: :D take it easy . i'm not hacker or black hat's member , just i want to learn php and this type injection and etc to be a Certified Ethical Hacker . :) tnQ for Reply

Comment: @sorroshsaket - OK I've checked the code that you linked to, but I can't open the example page (doesn't matter really). I would avoid these SQL injection examples on a live website anyway, unless you own it. The code **is not SQL injection safe**. For obvious reasons, I will reserve my further comments on where exactly it has weak points, but it should be clear to anyone that calls himself a programmer these days, if they bother to check the source code. The only attempt at _input parameter sanitization_ is declared in `cleaner` function in `include\funks.php`. It is easily exploitable!

Comment: @sorroshsaket - using scripts developed by others is fraught with danger if you don't understand them. Linking them here is also not ideal, and under some regulations could be construed as aiding an attack (see the EFF's comments on the latest proposed US regs) so I have deleted those comments.

Comment: @TildalWave [Sec.SE does not discriminate on hat color](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/117/should-we-allow-questions-answers-that-appear-to-include-or-request-exploit-code).

Comment: @TildalWave - It is easily exploitable! ? how? :S
. can u explain more?

Comment: @sorroshsaket - I already pointed you to the source code location. This is the main problem in it: `$output = htmlspecialchars(trim($input),ENT_QUOTES);` and the manual for the `htmlspecialchars` is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). I won't hint more than that it's plain and simple for anyone that can construct a simple MySQL query without using double or single quote characters that become their HTML encoded counterparts, or comment out parts of an existing query to bypass login credentials check. [The rest is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1KIMiKTKPw) ;)

Comment: @TildalWave - i can not understand  :S . i know this script will change ' and " by htmlspecialchars but how can i write entry for inject without using double or single quote characters? and ur youtube link is not valid :)

Comment: @sorroshsaket - /* The Youtube link works for me, but essentially, [it's this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086837/trivia?item=tr0748225). There's a hint in it how to construct the MySQL query you're after, especially the latter quote from the Arthur C. Clarke's _2001: A Space Odyssey_ novel (that was also later used in the sequel movie _2010_). You don't need to change any settings in the _INI_ file to exploit it, tho. Sorry, but I can't be more direct than this, it is not a theory anymore when it works on production websites. */

Comment: @TildalWave - Congratulations, you gained the _endless patience award_!

Comment: I see how the injection works, but what exactly does it accomplish? What could a malicious adversary do? Could you provide various examples? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, so in the example, the attacker is able to log in by only knowing someone's username and entering that SQL injection into the password field?

Comment: @trusktr - That is correct. I also suggest you read up on other questions and their answers tagged [tag:sql-injection]. If however you have an additional question that was not previously covered, please post it as a [new question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

TildalWave has a great answer, but there is a great mediation to SQL injection that was missing from the answer. Prepared Statements. As Tildal said the entire statement with user input is parsed with no parsable distinction between variables and constant parts of the statement. The solution is sending the constant part of the statement with variable placeholders then the variables. PDO is what I use for my SQL interaction. Here is the function I use...

```
function _SQL_QUERY($_base_request, $_request_arguments)
{
                $_DB_USERNAME = "bob"; $_DB_PASSWORD="secret"; $_DB_LOCATION="localhost"; $_DB_NAME="MYWICKEDDATABASE"; $_DB_SERVER_TYPE="mysql";
                if(!isset($_DATABASE_CONNECTION))
                {
                        $_DATABASE_CONNECTION = new PDO("$_DB_SERVER_TYPE:dbname=$_DB_NAME;host=$_DB_LOCATION;charset=utf8", $_DB_USERNAME, $_DB_PASSWORD);
                        $_DATABASE_CONNECTION->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                }
                $__STMT = $_DATABASE_CONNECTION->prepare($_base_request);
                if($__STMT->execute($_request_arguments))
                {
                        return $__STMT;
                }
                else
                {
/*
        //Helpful ONLY when debugging!!!
                        echo 'ERROR</ br>';
                        echo $_base_request;
                        echo '</ br>';
                        print_r($__STMT->errorInfo());
                        print_r($_request_arguments);
                        die('</ br>');
*/
                        return false;
                }
}
```

to use it you would just need to run this

```
_SQL_QUERY("Select * FROM names WHERE name=:var1 AND age=:var2", array('var1'=>'jim','var2'=>50));
```

There are plenty of improvements to be made (mainly functionaly) to this but it is a vast improvement to the traditional SQL functions. BTW its important to know that if a row has a failed attempt at an injection in it's data, a backup and restore may actually make it successful depending on the method used. Kudos for doing a security audit of your code, if only more people learned programming with that motivation towards security.

Comment: this is very nice & i read about it . I like it , but there are many way to stop injection like set input on this function: mysql_real_escape_string($post[username])  but i want to show this team there is a big hole on their login form but when i inject the query " will change to &qout; and i have no idea for this

Comment: David thanks for your answer! @sorroshsaket - [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) alone isn't safe enough to prevent SQL injections, and prepared statements are one suggested way to prevent them, on top of string escaping. Both of it together are considered input parameter _sanitization_, where string escaping can be considered _normalization_ only and not enough. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/1953464), also these two: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2353687/1953464), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5433536/1953464).

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is.
You are not validating anything.
You have to use

- `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection
- `htmlentities`/`htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS attacks

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.thecodertips.com/2012/08/sql-injection-security-tutorial-web.html) as it helps on learning to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Would the down voter be prepared to explain why?  Is the linked tutorial not good (or was the down vote for grammar??!) ?  I am starting for a position of knowing little about the subject, so can't judge the quality of the information.  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't know about the reasons for the down-vote, but it's a general consensus (and the practice has proven it) that using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) alone isn't sufficient. See @David's answer and also links in my comment below it. For more on the subject of sanitizing input parameters, and mitigating all kinds of other possible threats, [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org) should always be high on the list too. The blog you attached the link to isn't sufficiently covering this topic, tho. There are no magic bullets in IT Security. :)